# How to manage index state in Amazon OpenSearch Serverless?

Tags: amazon-opensearch

We are moving from traditional self managed OpenSearch cluster to Amazon OpenSearch Serverless.
Index is created daily with date pattern, and I want to add policy to delete index after few days. I used IndexManagement/StateManagementPolicies before to accomplish this in Amazon OpenSearch (traditional managed cluster).

How can I accomplish this in Amazon OpenSearch Serverless?
I cannot find a way to access IndexManagement, even after providing my user all permissions via Data Access Policy.

providing my user all permissions via Data Access Policy, and I expect user to see Index Management in OpenSearch Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from AWS support.
As of Aug 2023, Opensearch Serverless does not support Index State Management to automate index managements (Its only available in AWS Opensearch Managed cluster). To delete unwated index, cleanup has to be a manual operation or via delete index APIs.

Comment: Why are you creating an index everyday? That does not sound the best way to use indexes

Comment: OpenSearch/ElasticSearch cannot delete documents by age automatically, but it can delete index by age. Our reason for this approach is to recycle older logs by deleting per day indexes via ISM-Policy. To search logs, we use index patterns to search across these indexes. We have no issues with search performance via this approach. It sounds strange compared to indexing concepts, but this seems to be the way when using OpenSearch for log management.